# DB::table('table')->select returning empty string Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel 6 with Vue axios, I want to populate a form-select with what I have in my "fjl_groups" table. But everytime I check the console for the result it is returning me an empty string, any idea why is this? My Laravel logs aren't returning any error either, so I have no idea what's going on.

**Vue's part**

```
<b-col cols="4">
    <label for="editorial">Group</label>
    <b-form-select v-model="group" :options="groups" id="groups" name="groups"></b-form-select>
</b-col>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            group: null,
            groups: [{
                value: null,
                text: 'Select'
            }]
        }
    },

    created(){
        axios.get('/clubs/create')
            .then(res => {
                this.groups = res.data;
                console.log(this.groups);
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            })
    },
    }
}
</script>
```

I have a club and I want to assign a group for it from the ones I have added in my database, this is why I have it like that.

My controller (ClubsController)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Club;
use App\Models\Group;
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            DB::table('fjl_groups')->select('id as value', 'nom as text')->get();
        }
        else{
            return view('clubs.create');
        }
    }
```

**Group Model**

```
class Group extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'fjl_groups';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning a value. You're just performing the select.

Try returning it:

```
return response()->json([
  'data' => DB::table('fjl_groups')->select('id as value', 'nom as text')->get()
]);
```

Comment: I did this and it's returning a weird array: `Object { readyState: Getter & Setter, getResponseHeader: Getter & Setter, getAllResponseHeaders: Getter & Setter, setRequestHeader: Getter & Setter, overrideMimeType: Getter & Setter, statusCode: Getter & Setter, abort: Getter & Setter, state: Getter & Setter, always: Getter & Setter, catch: Getter & Setter, … }`